# How to make iwconfig fully work on embedded Linux

Tags: wifi, usb, embedded, cross-compilation

The target embedded Linux is ARM Xilinx Zynq, and I am working in CentOS to compile to ARM using Xilinx's tool.  The target OS is working now and I want to setup the wifi using `iwconfig`.

I downloaded wireless tool from hp using git, and tried to cross compile it by modifying the Makefile to use the cross compiler

```
cc = arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc
```

And it seems working since I can run iwconfig after copied everything to the target.  I can turn on the usb wifi now (ASUS USB-N13, `rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin` is copied to `/lib/firmware/rtlwifi`). I had to manually copy the .so files into the `/lib` directory on the target to let it run.  However, when I run further tools, an error shows up saying

```
can't find /proc/net/wireless
```

I know this is a virtual file, so what should I do to let it work?  I know if I install the iwconfig it will complete everything.  So do I need gcc to run on the target ARM to install it, or can I cross compile it on CentOS and make the changes to the target build, to be included in the kernel image file?